# Prove subset of transformations is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that the subset of linear transformations given below is a group:

Let $T^n$ denote the n-fold composition of any $T∈ℒ(V)$. For instance, the two fold composition $T\circ T$ is denoted $T^2$.

Let $T∈ℒ(V)$ such that $T≠I$ and $T^n=I$. Show that $C_n=\{I^{},T^{},T^2,...T^{n−1}\}$ is a group.

Comment: Which of the group axioms can't you prove?

Comment: Closure under composition

Comment: Given $T^n=I$, that shouldn't be too difficult though. Note that $T^iT^j=T^{i+j}$, because of associativity of composition.

Comment: Why though? I'm taking $T^n$ to refer to a specific transformation, not as the definition for all transformations.

Comment: Sure. You are wondering why the set is closed under composition. Prove that the composition of two of its elements is still in it. But the elements can be written $T^i$ and $T^j$, and the composition is $T^{i+j}$. Either $i+j\le n$ and there is nothing to prove, either $i+j>n$ but then $T^{i+j}=T^nT^{i+j-n}$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, so I did get to the point where I could break out the cases that way and easily proved the $i + j \leq n$ case, but I can't figure out the $i + j \gt n$ case. I figured that stipulating "this is only true when $i + j \leq n$" would be a cop-out, but maybe it really is that simple?

Comment: If $i+j>n$ for $0\le i<n$ and $0\le j<n$, then $T^iT^j=T^{i+j}=T^nT^{i+j-n}=T^{i+j-n}$ and $T^{i+j-n}$ is clearly in your set, as $0<i+j-n<n$.

Comment: Oooh. Thank you. I wasn't sure how to go about proving that $i + j - n \lt n$ , but I'll just take it for granted.

Comment: If $i<n$ and $j<n$, then obviously $i+j<2n$, so $i+j-n<n$.